# android import and text id error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This code:

```
package ir.blog.alilolo.justjava;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * This app displays an order form to order coffee.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
     */
    public void submitOrder(View view) {
        display(1);
    }

    /**
     * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
     */
    private void display(int number) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
    }
}
```

The `R` symbol is red and gives Error and when I add `import android.R`, it disappears but then `activity_main` and `quantity_text_view` become red and again  I see Errors! What should i do?

**Note**: I've defined text view ids (I have three text view and both of them have id!)

Comment: import R.ir.blog.alilolo.justjava or whatever your base package is

Comment: What? Should I add exactly "import R.ir.blog.alilolo.justjava"?! It doesn't work.

Comment: Try this, remove the android.R import, hover over the red R in your code, hit ALT + ENTER and accept the import Studio suggests. If that doesn't work Build > Rebuild project and try again

Comment: There are no import suggests. It only includes creating classes , interfaces and ...

Comment: And when I rebuild it doesn't work and again I see the Error

Comment: And you tried seeing the Studio suggestions after the rebuild? You could possibly have corrupted resources. Did you add some new Strings or anything else to your resources when the errors started to occur?

Comment: No! But another point is that before I see this Error ,  I tried to auto import( because of another problem) so I accepted invalidation and restart(for changes) and after that I saw that not only the previous problem was fixed  but also these problems had appeared

Comment: The problem you're having is that you need an R class (which is auto-generated from your resources). Android does the same thing for its resources too, hence android.R. But you need you own R. In theory rebuilding should generate it. Keep an eye on your build log for errors. What is your base package though?

Comment: Did my answer below work out for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a somewhat common error with Android.

When ever this happens please try the following:

Go to the `Build` menu at the top and in the drop down select `Clean Project`. Once that is completed do the same but instead of clicking `Clean Project`, you will click `Rebuild Project`.

If this does not fix the error, please try the following as suggested by Raju in the comments:

Try syncing with `Gradle` and/or with File System. This can be found under the `File Settings` menu bar in Android Studio. If this fails to fix the issue, try the `Invalidate Caches / Restart` option.

Finally if that doesn't work try deleting and recreating your ptoject.

Comment: Also want to add: try syncing with `Gardle` and/or `with File System`. It can be found under File Settings menu bar in Android Studio. Or at last if nothing works `Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Comment: @Raju edited. Thank you. I have never had to go that far but I know it could work.

Comment: I believe Rebuild Project actually does a Clean Project first

Comment: You may be right. Can you find documentation to back it up? I always do both but I could be wrong. I don't want to update the answer with invalid info so if you can provide docs I will be happy to update it.

Comment: No. They didn't work ; I deleted the project and again made it . :(  but It worked! :)